# Setting up a specific UITableViewCell Layout

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I am trying to find the best route to setting up a custom `UITableViewCell` Layout. This is the layout I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The colourful part represents an imageview. The `UIImageView` appears to over hang the edges of the cell.

But from what I can gather this would actually be the whole cell. I understand that the cell has multiple different views like content, background but not sure how to implement this.

I have tried in IB but I think this is too custom. How do I create a cell like this with an overhang as such and a custom layout for the cell.

Comment: What difficulties are you having with IB? -- it seems a simple thing to accomplish.

Comment: Well in IB if I set the cell type Custom, and table style plain. I cannot drag the imageview larger than the cell. Also I cannot make the width not the full screen width. So indented like the image above

Comment: So put a grey border in the cell, and have the imageView overhang the border.

Comment: So the white part should just be a UIView within the cell?

Comment: Yes, you can do it that way. Make the cell the size of the gray view you show. Add a white view, then add the image view and the other content you show.

Comment: How do I then deal with the background color on select, as I would want only the white area to change color, not the grey

Comment: Make the white area a UIControl, and trigger the color change and segue there instead of in the cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot set subViews out of the `UITableViewCell` frame.

Here's a easy way to do what you want:

1) Change the background of your custom cell to `[UIColor clearColor]`. You can do this either in the interface builder of in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

I'm assuming this grey color it's the color of your `UITableView`.

Here's a picture of the cell with clear color background

[image]

2) Inside your custom cell, put a white `UIView` with a padding to the edges of the cell, simulating your original Cell, like this:

[image]

3) Then, just add the rest of your subViews as you want. You can add then above but not inside the white UIView, that simulates the original cell. It will look like this:

[image]

**EDIT**

Answering to your last question. Well, in this case, you would have to create your own custom selection. Fortunately, this is very simple.

First of all, I'm assuming you have a subclass of `UITableViewCell`. So, just create a `IBOutlet`, in your customCell, to our white `UIView` that represents our fake cell. I'm calling this `IBOutlet` as `containerView`.

Then, override the method `setSelected:animated:` **inside** your custom cell and do all the custom selection behaviour you want. An easy example would be like this:

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = selected ? [UIColor blueColor] : [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

In my example, `[UIColor blueColor]` is the color when the cell is selected, and `[UIColor whiteColor]` is the normal state color. Obviously, you can change this for any other colors you like.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I then change the selection for the cell. I would need only the white view to change background colour and not the whole cell on selection?

Comment: Sure, that's easy. I edited my answer explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

See this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, although I already know how to setup a custom cell it this specific layout/view that I am having problems with.